# Jquery what is the difference between .find and simply a space between ancestor and descendant?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find, ancestor, descendant

`$("div .product");`  selects elements with class of product that have a div ancestor
`$("div").find(".product");`  does the exact same as far as I can see.

Both work fine for me.
I would like to know which I should use, in order to streamline my code?

Answer (score 3):

Find is particularly useful if you already have an jQuery object with the parent elements:

```
var $elements = $("div");
// some code that does other stuff with $elements
// ...
// then
var $products = $elements.find(".product");
```

Or even if you have a direct reference to a DOM element that is the parent/ancestor:

```
$(domElementRef).find(".product");
// or inside an event handler where 'this' is the DOM element the event applied to:
$(this).find(".product");
```

If you don't need to do any kind of processing on the parent/ancestor element(s) it's fine to just use the combined selector with `$("div .product")`.